# Is it sane to include casts in #defined constants based on how they're intended to be used?

Tags: c

Say I have a bunch of un-magicked constants that have been given symbolic names in the header file of a gyroscope module `gyro.h`:

```
#define GYRO_SPI_TIMEOUT 1000
```

In this instance, the hardware abstraction libraries for my MCU use `uint32_t` for the number of milliseconds. Is it sensible to, in lieu of allocating space and defining these as `const`, add type information in the macro?

```
#define GYRO_SPI_TIMEOUT ((uint32_t) 1000)
```

What are the benefits and drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Hard to see a benefit when you can use `1000U`

Comment: Is there any practical reasons to have the extra cast? In most cases you won't need it: for example for the value assignment in an uint32_t or for passing the value to a function with an `uint32_t` parameter. For the rare cases you'd need the cast, you can add it explicitly.

Comment: @HansPassant: it is different. Here's an example: `short s = ((uint32_t) 1000)` - doesn't compile; `short s = 1000U` compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using the [`[U]INT<n>_C` macros from `stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html#tag_13_48_03_04) instead (you may need to scroll down to where it says "Macros for Integer Constant Expressions").

The main advantage of these macros, over casts, is that constants defined with them are usable in more contexts.  For instance, `((uint32_t)1234)` cannot appear in an `#if` expression, but `UINT32_C(1234)` can.

Note that most C compilers will not complain about assignments of a constant expression that involve a narrowing conversion, unless the conversion actually changes the value.  For instance, given

```
short a = 1234UL;
short b = ((unsigned long)1234);
short c = 65537UL;
short d = ((unsigned long)65537);
```

gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5 issue diagnostics about the conversion *only* for `c` and `d`, even when I crank the warnings up as high as they will go.

Comment: It looks like you're right about using `UINTN_C` macros. Though your last statement seems inconsistent with the documentation. The macro would expand to an integer constant `1234UL` (or whatever combination of Ls will make it at least 32-bits wide). That *should* generate a warning when you assign it to a shorter value, right?

Comment: @josaphatv Most compilers silently accept `short a = <integer literal>`, regardless of what suffixes the integer literal has, unless the assignment actually changes the numeric value.  So, `short a = 1234UL;` goes through without complaint, but `short a = 65537UL;` warns.

Comment: @josaphatv ... upon experimentation, I can't persuade gcc to warn about `short a = ((unsigned long)1234)` either, not even with absurdly aggressive warnings settings.

Comment: Suggested use of `[U]INT<n>_C` does not clarify here an important point: `UINT32_C(1234)` does not create type `uint32_t`, but `uint_least32_t`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider this a good thing to do, especially ensuring the correct signedness (for this purpose, `1000u` would be enough, though). Arithmetic types aren't strongly typed in C, so most code wouldn't change semantics if the macro expansion has the correct signedness and is promoted (that is, not smaller than `int`).

There are static analysers and options for compilers, however, which do some more type checking and disallow certain implicit conversions, where it would be nice if your constants behaved as if they were variables for most purposes for the code using your header.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is often done. In fact, the infamous `NULL` pointer is often defined like this:

`#define NULL ((void*)0)`

**Advantages**: your macro is now typesafe, whatever the global constant proponents say.

**Disadvantages**: if you will want to use it in an un-typesafe way, say, like this:

`short a = GYRO_SPI_TIMEOUT;`

You'd need a cast. However, if you're not intending for such usages to ever happen, this can be a good thing.